# Retrofit, no muestra la lista de ciudades al buscar en el dialogo del floating action button

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

Pues eso, he implementado una aplicación con 3 tabs y quiero actualizar todos los tabs al hacer click cuando muestra las ciudades en el diálogo, el caso es que ni siquiera me muestra las ciudades, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Mi adapter:

```
public class RegionsAutocompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {


    private Context mContext;
    private List<Prediction> resultList = new ArrayList<Prediction>();

    public RegionsAutocompleteAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Prediction getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getItem(position).getDescription());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            /*
                SEGUN LA DOCUMENTACIÓN DE ANDROID, ESTE MÉTODO NO SE INVOCA
                EN EL HILO UI, POR LO QUE NO ES NECESARIO QUE EL PROGRAMADOR
                SE ENCARGUE DE LA GESTIÓN DE LOS HILOS.
             */
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                //Resultado del filtrado.
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {

                    List<Prediction> places = autoComplete(mContext, constraint.toString());

                    // Asignamos los valores recogidos al FilterResults
                    if (places != null ) {
                        filterResults.values = places;
                        filterResults.count = places.size();
                    } else {
                        filterResults.values = null;
                        filterResults.count = 0;
                    }

                }
                return filterResults;
            }

             /*
                SEGUN LA DOCUMENTACIÓN DE ANDROID, ESTE MÉTODO SI SE INVOCA
                EN EL HILO UI, Y RECIBE DEL MÉTODO ANTERIOR LOS RESULTADOS
                A MOSTRAR. NO DEBEMOS TEMER UN FALLO DEL LOOPER POR INTENTAR
                MODIFICAR LA UI DESDE OTRO HILO.
             */

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    resultList = (List<Prediction>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }


    /*
        EN ESTE MÉTODO, LA PETICIÓN QUE HACEMOS ES SÍNCRONA, YA QUE
        ANDROID SE ENCARGARÁ DE EJECUTARLO EN UN HILO INDEPENDIENTE
     */
    private List<Prediction> autoComplete(Context context, String input) {

        List<Prediction> result = null;

        //Desde el contexto llegamos a nuestra clase Application
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            Activity act = (Activity) context;

            AutocompleteApp application =
                    (AutocompleteApp) act.getApplication();

            Retrofit retrofit = application.getRetrofitGoogle();
            //Obtenemos nuestra instancia "singleton" de Retrofit
            //Retrofit retrofit = ((AutoCompleteApplication) act.getApplication()).getRetrofitGoogle();

            //Creamos el API
            IGoogleRegionsApi api = retrofit.create(IGoogleRegionsApi.class);
            //Obtenemos la petición lista para realizarla
            Call<Region> callAutoComplete = api.loadAutocompleteRegions(input);

            try {
                //La ejecutamos con execute
                result = callAutoComplete.execute().body().getPredictions();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //Gestión del error
                Log.e("ERROR IO", e.getMessage());
                //Devolvemos el resultad
            }

        }

        return result;


    }
```

Mi dialogo:

```
public class DialogoBusquedaFragment extends DialogFragment {

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialogo_busqueda, null);

        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_dialogo_busqueda);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new RegionsAutocompleteAdapter(getContext()));
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Prediction prediction = (Prediction) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                autoCompleteTextView.setText(prediction.getDescription());
                DialogoBusquedaFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setView(v);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Clase para consumir:

```
public class AutocompleteApp extends Application {

    private static Retrofit retrofitGoogle, retrofitOpenWeather;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .create();


        retrofitGoogle = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(initHttp())
                .build();

        retrofitOpenWeather = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.openweather.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

    }

    //Podemos crear un interceptor para cada caso que necesitemos
    private static OkHttpClient initHttp() {

        Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

                Request original = chain.request();

                HttpUrl originalHttpUrl = original.httpUrl();

                HttpUrl url = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                        .addQueryParameter("location","37.380413,-6.007445")
                        .addQueryParameter("radius","50000")
                        .addQueryParameter("types", "(cities)")
                        .addQueryParameter("language","es_ES")
                        .addQueryParameter("key","AIzaSyArgRhpfCPo35NAixPkc3OaZAE03xWfTxo")
                        .build();


                Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build();


                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        };

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.interceptors().add(interceptor);

        return client;

    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitGoogle() {
        return retrofitGoogle;
    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitOpenWeather() { return retrofitOpenWeather; }

}
```

Método creado en la clase main para mostrar el diálogo:

```
//Método para mostrar el diálogo de búsqueda
    private void showSearchDialog() {
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogoBusquedaFragment();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialogo");
        dialogFragment.setCancelable(false);

    }
```

Floating action button de la clase Main:

```
  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

              showSearchDialog();
            }
        });
```

Interfaz:

```
public interface IGoogleRegionsApi {

    @GET("maps/api/place/autocomplete/json")
    Call<Region> loadAutocompleteRegions(@Query("input") String input);
}
```

Comment: @ jose ya probaste que en verdad se obtengan datos ? :  result = callAutoComplete.execute().body().getPredictions();

Comment: Sí, ya que en otro ejemplo lo he probado y muestra, el ejemplo del profesor, pero mostrado en una caja de texto y no en un dialog, con delay incluido